# IF AND Formula Google Sheets Help

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a formula that can match 2 criteria and if the match is TRUE then it returns the average of the range provided.

Criteria are:

- User ID
- Week number.

So for the user id provided, I want it to match it with the week number and then return the average of that week from the whole range.

I tried below, though I may know what is wrong with it I cannot really find a solution for it.

`=IF(and('Stockholm perf'!A5:A32=$A3,'Stockholm perf'!C3:AB3=C$2),AVERAGE('Stockholm perf'!C5:AB32),"WRONG")`

Comment: Am I guessing that column A contains the IDs and columns C to AB contain the values ​​of each of the 26 weeks?

Comment: Ok, so in sheet 1. 

IDs are in Column A.

C3:AB3 have the week numbers, let'say 13.

Then the row below are the days. Mon to Sun. For these days if they belong to week 13 then C3:AB3 will contain 13 from Mon to Sun.

The data that needs to be averaged is in between C5:AB32.

Now in another sheet called "Summary". I would like to match the ID with the week number 13 which indicates Mon to Sun (there are 7 different values for each week + other weeks also), then take the average of that person in that week and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in columns A (id), B (week number), and C (the data you want to average), then your formula is:

`=query(A2:D,"select avg(C) where A="&G2&" and B="&G3)`

where G2 contains the desired ID and G3 contains the desired week number.